# Restrict VSFTPD virtual user to respective directory

Tags: php, permissions, ftp

I'm using `Ubuntu 13.10` with `vsftpd`, and trying to limit a FTP user to their respective directory.

For this, I am using the following

My vsftpd.conf :

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/sites/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

I configured `pam.d/vsftpd`create virtual users for FTP as follows :

```
htpasswd -cd /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd USERNAME
useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid nogroup -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd

mkdir /var/www/sites/USERNAME
chmod -w /var/www/sites/USERNAME
mkdir /var/www/sites/USERNAME/www
chmod -R 755 /var/www/sites/USERNAME/www
chown -R vsftpd:nogroup /var/www/sites/USERNAME
```

The setup if for running simple PHP websites, and the above setup works fine, and when connected I can view only the my directory.

The problem is when I have a file like :

```
<?php
exec('cat /var/www/SOME_OTHER_USER_FILE', $output);
print_r($output);
```

It prints the contents of files, which are outside of the user's directory. How can I avoid this?

Note : The permissions of the dir are as follows :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsftpd nogroup 4096 Apr  5 04:55 .
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 Mar 23 10:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsftpd nogroup  113 Apr  5 04:44 index.php
```

How can I avoid a user navigating outside of the assigned directory? I've tried searching for it, but cannot seem to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't a ftp problem, but a php problem, try to use in your virtualhost

```
php_value open_basedir "/dir_of_your_virtualhost
```

in this you php can only work in that directory